# How can I create anonymous method in a lambda expression using C# like I can in VB.NET?

Tags: c#, .net, lambda, anonymous-methods

In VB.NET, I can do this:

```
MyArray.Select(Function(a)
                   Dim x as string
                   x = a
                   Return x
               End Function)
```

How can I do this in c#?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
myArray.Select(a => {
    ...
});
```

Answer (score 1):

It looks like the VB.Net is just selecting each element in MyArray, in c#

```
MyArray.Select(a => (string) a);
```

To make it a method, use braces:

```
MyArray.Select(a =>
 {
   ...
   return ...;
 });
```